# Map attributes in xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have XML like this:

```
<qualification name="access">
    <attribute name="abc">OK</attribute>
    <attribute name="res">OK 2</attribute>
    <requesturi>http://stackoverflow.com</requesturi>
</qualification>
```

Class is:

```
public class Qualification {
  @XStreamAsAttribute
  private String name;

  private String requesturi;
}
```

How can I map `<attribute name="abc">OK</attribute>`

Comment: If you were using a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation the could just leverage the `@XmlValue` annotation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing attribute converter. Problem is solved.

```
package com.xstream;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAsAttribute;

public class Attribute {

  @XStreamAsAttribute
  private String name;

  private String value;

  public Attribute(String name, String value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  /**
   * @return the name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * @param name the name to set
   */
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  /**
   * @return the value
   */
  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  /**
   * @param value the value to set
   */
  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  /* (non-Javadoc)
   * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
   */
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Attribute [name=" + name + ", value=" + value + "]";
  }

}
```

`AttributeConverter` class is:

```
package com.xstream;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

public class AttributeConverter implements Converter{

  @Override
  public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return clazz.equals(Attribute.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void marshal(Object object, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    System.out.println("object = " + object.toString());
    Attribute attribute = (Attribute) object;
    writer.addAttribute("name", attribute.getName());  
    writer.setValue(attribute.getValue());  

  }

  @Override
  public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
    return new Attribute(reader.getAttribute("name"), reader.getValue());

  } 

}
```

Use this in Qualification class as:

```
  @XStreamConverter(AttributeConverter.class)
  private Attribute attribute;
```

Register converter in main class as:

```
xstream.registerConverter(new AttributeConverter());
```